# How to export as a pipe-delimited file using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

This code creates a comma-separated file, I need to convert that to the pipe-delimited format. How to do that?

```shell
$DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-csv  "G:\Text.txt" -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-delimiter` parameter specified in the online help for [export-csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7.4&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-7)

```shell
$DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-csv "G:\Text.txt" -NoTypeInformation -delimiter "|"
```